# Can not graphically log into any user account - tty1 works

Tags: 14.04, login

I recently did an update on a Ubuntu 14.04.1 running in a vmplayer and after the update I can't do a graphically login. Login using terminal it's ok <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>
Google give some hits about deleting / permissions with ~./Xautorithy file but no success.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't do a graphically login? Is there a GUI at all? What happens?

If you still have the /.Xauthority instead of deleting have you tried to `sudo chown yourusername:yourusername .Xauthority` and logging in/restarting?

Comment: .Xauthority has joao:joao (my user in this case). I've a GUI to login , I did a video , here you can see it http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cpC470g1ZSI

Comment: Hm, not sure. I'd  also check to make sure the permissions look something like this -rw------- as these seem to be the default. If you can login as the guest though then we would know that the problem has to deal with the user settings.

Comment: Other possible commands you could run in a tty terminal would be "xauth list", "ps x | grep X11" and looking for odd behaviour/output. Generating a new .Xauthority is the only other thing I could think of, anything else would be beyond my scope of knowledge.

Comment: -rw-------  1 joao joao    54 Fev 21 18:16 .Xauthority
-rw-------  1 joao joao  3215 Fev 21 18:16 .xsession-errors

Comment: I did some tests and this seems to be related to the Nvidia graphics...